# get address of pointer to first element of array and copy all elements to new buffer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, double-pointer

I'm doing the following:

Let's say I have an array:

```
uint8 Array[100] = {25,33,48,20,.....};
```

There exist a function which is doing the following:

```
void getValues(uint8 **pvalues)
{
    *pvalues =&Array[0];        //Saves the address of first element of Array[]
}
```

later in my code I have following:

```
uint8 *pmyValues;
uint8 myBuffer[100];
uint8 i=0;

getValues(&pmyValues)

for (i;i<100;i++)
{
   (void)memcpy(&myBuffer[i], (uint8*)&pmyValues[i], sizeof(uint8));        
}
```

I want to have the values from Array ow in my own internal buffer pmyBuffer
After debugging I see that pmyBuffer is containing an array of pointers!?
Not sure what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to pointers in C and would be thankful I somebody can provide help.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `pmyBuffer` defined? It also looks like you're trying to copy `getValues` byte-by-byte but your call to `memcpy` is copying 8 bytes at a time. Further, you can copy the whole array with one call to `memcpy` and no loop.

Comment: It was a copy paste failure. Have corrected now.

Comment: Did the change to `memcpy` fix your issue? You could do `memcpy(myBuffer, pmyValues, 100 * sizeof(uint8));` Without the loop.

Comment: What, specifically, do you see that makes you think `pmyValues` "contains" an array of pointers?  What it contains -- or at least how that is interpreted -- is determined by its type.  It being a pointer to `uint8_t`, the thing (if any) that its value points to is a `uint8_t`, possibly the first of an array of the same.

Comment: Your code should have copied the content of `Array`. Maybe your debugger could not guess in what format you wanted it...

Comment: I would be more inclined to believe that a debugger guessed that **in function `getValues()`**, the parameter `pvalues` corresponds to an array of pointers, because it could, and in at least one sense *it does*.  But in that sense, `getValues()` would be interpreted to set the value of the first element of the pointer array as a pointer to the first element of your `uint8_t` array, which is exactly what you appear to want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presented code by you in the question does not make sense. If you want to

> get address of pointer to first element of array and copy all elements
>   to new buffer

then you can just write

```
memcpy( myBuffer, Array, 100 * sizeof( *Array ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    uint8_t Array[N] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J' };
    uint8_t myBuffer[N];

    memcpy( myBuffer, Array, N * sizeof( *Array ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        putchar( myBuffer[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

If by some reason you need to use an intermediate pointer then the code can look something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void getValues( uint8_t **pvalues, uint8_t Array[] )
{
    *pvalues = Array;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    uint8_t Array[N] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J' };
    uint8_t myBuffer[N];

    uint8_t *pmyValues;

    getValues( &pmyValues, Array );

    memcpy( myBuffer, pmyValues, N * sizeof( *pmyValues ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        putchar( myBuffer[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```